# What is the last version of Selenium for Java 5?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm obliged to use Java 5 to implement Selenium tests (precisely JDK 1.5.22) and classes of the last version of Selenium (2.42.2) are compiled in Java 6 or more.

What is the last version of Selenium I can use?

For information, I use Selenium through Maven:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.42.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [project changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) says:

```
v2.22.0
=======

WebDriver:
  * JRE dependency upped to Java 6.
```

which implies that v2.21.0 still supported Java 5. Checking [the pom for that release](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-parent/2.21.0/selenium-parent-2.21.0.pom) shows:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.5</source>
    <target>1.5</target>
```

so that looks like a good place to start.

Note that JDK 5 [has been unsupported since 2009](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer (per the [release notes](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/category/releases/)) is `2.19` -

The May 29 2012 release notes for [`2.22`](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/announcing-selenium-2-22/) read (in part) -

> **Selenium 2.22 is the first version that requires Java 6**

it also notes that

> Since Java 5 was ["end of lifed" in 2009](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html), we don’t expect this to impact many users.

and if scroll down one entry we see the previous release was on Wednesday the 8th of February 2012 and the [previous](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/announcing-selenium-2-19-the-prancing-unicorn-release/) release was version `2.19`

Comment: Thank you. However, the last verison is the 2.21.0.

Comment: @Zistoloen I'm pretty sure that was a development (not release) version. But if it works for your purposes then by all means.

Comment: OK thanks for clarification. The version 2.21.0 works for my purposes.